# SQL query to search for a record in one table and replace it with multiple records from another table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, sql-insert

I have two tables - package and subpackage as:

```
CREATE TABLE Package (
    Sequence int PRIMARY KEY,
    Package int,
    Mnemonic char(3),
    MnemonicValue int
);

CREATE TABLE SubPackage (
    Sequence int PRIMARY KEY,
    SubPackage int,
    Mnemonic char(3),
    MnemonicValue int
);

INSERT INTO Package (Sequence, Package, Mnemonic, MnemonicValue)
VALUES (1, 111, 'XXX', 0), (2, 111, 'SUB', 153), (3, 111, 'DDD', 30), (4, 111, 'YYY', 20), (5, 111, 'ZZZ', 1000);

INSERT INTO SubPackage (Sequence, SubPackage, Mnemonic, MnemonicValue)
VALUES (1, 153, 'AAA', 20), (2, 153, 'BBB', 1000), (3, 153, 'CCC', 30);
```

The requirement is to search for a Mnemonic 'SUB' in the package table and replace the SUB record with the records from 'Subpackage' table for the mapped Mnemonic Value (153) and resequence the sequence values as shown in the [Result][2] table.

I have tried using the update statement as:

```
UPDATE package
SET    Mnemonic = subpackage.Mnemonic
FROM   package
       INNER JOIN subpackage
       ON package.MnemonicValue = subpackage.SubPackage
```

But this replaces the SUB record from package table with only AAA record from subpackage table. I want SUB record to be replaced with all records from subpackage table and re-sequence it in a new table as shown in the Result table.

Desired result:

```
Sequence | Particular | Mnemonic | MnemonicValue

       1 |         111|       XXX|             0        
       2 |         111|       AAA|            20
       3 |         111|       BBB|          1000
       4 |         111|       CCC|            30
       5 |         111|       DDD|            30
       6 |         111|       YYY|            20
       7 |         111|       ZZZ|          1000
```

Comment: You've tagging MySQL, SQL Server & Oracle? They are 3 separate RDBMS - which are you actually interested? Please adjust your tags.

Comment: Also for SO question images are *not* desirable, instead please format data as text.

Comment: @Max . . . I removed the inconsistent database tags.  This seems to require `merge`, which is rather database dependent, so the appropriate database tag is quite important.

Comment: And now you have removed the formatting? Please use the code format option in the question to layout code and data in a readable way.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I've added the database tag

Comment: @Max What version of MySQL are you using? Is it by chance v8?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't think you can update Package table to get exactly result that you want, i.e. problem is that in your example you reordering `Sequence` column.

Anyway, here is SQL script(based on answer by GMB) that will generate result that you want to get:

```
select
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY p.Sequence) as Sequence,
    p.Package,
    coalesce(s.Mnemonic, p.Mnemonic) Mnemonic,
    coalesce(s.MnemonicValue, p.MnemonicValue) MnemonicValue
from Package p
left join SubPackage s 
    on p.MnemonicValue = s.SubPackage
order by p.Sequence
```

But, AFAIK it works only with MySQL 8

Here is a [link to SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/321aa/1/0), but beware it's for Postgres(as SQLFiddle doesn't support MySQL 8).

If you're using earlier version of MySQL, you can [try to emulate row_number function](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-row_number/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `left join` to get the results that you want:

```
select
    p.sequence,
    p.package,
    coalesce(s.mnemonic, p.mnemonic) mnemonic,
    coalesce(s.mnemonic_value, p.mnemonic_value) mnemonic_value
from package p
left join sub_package s 
    on  p.mnemonic = 'SUB'
    and p.mnemonic_value = s.sub_package
```

"Replacing" the new rows is a bit more complicated. It would probably be simpler to insert the new rows, then remove the original (you can do this in a transaction):

```
start transaction;

insert into package(sequence, package, mnemonic, mnemonic_value)
select
    p.sequence,
    p.package,
    coalesce(s.mnemonic, p.mnemonic),
    coalesce(s.mnemonic_value, p.mnemonic_value)
from package p
left join sub_package s 
    on  p.mnemonic = 'SUB'
    and p.mnemonic_value = s.sub_package;

delete from package where mnemonic = 'SUB';

commit;
```

Comment: The records from package table are repeated and the sequence is also quite messed up